# Basic Google Maps/Mobile App integration questions

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I'm in the research (what's doable) phase of a possible app development project.

My potential app will be a trip app that lists all stores and drug stores. Is is possible for my app (regardless of platform) to integrate Google Maps (or some other maps database) to provide:

1. turn-by-turn guided directions?
2. interactive list of stores and drug stores between start and final destination so that I can choose my preferred stops?
3. calculate time/distance to each chosen stop?
4. ability to add other parameters to each stop?

I found another app that functions similar to my app idea but I'm not sure if the GPS navigation functionality and limitless list of places has to be built from scratch or can integrate with an existing tool like Google Maps API and if there's a charge if I'm charging for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can make requests like that. It might be best to build for the platform. Ie. If it's iOS use Apple Maps for ease of use, and google for Android. However, if you're going to build cross platform go with google. Might have it issue separate queries for different data.

Answer (score -1):

No they will be use normal google map API most of cases but if JavaScript call is increase they will buy premium plane because google provide 1000 JavaScript call in a day you will increase limit at 100000 by simply register you credit card which was well inaf for new comer also for mid range user and little bit heavy user.but in premium plan google give more facilities to there customer. you can get more info at https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/